# Google App Engine GitHub Action: Error: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, github-ci

I'm trying to deploy my Django API on to Google App Engine using GitHub CI/CD, but I'm getting a strange error that doesn't provide any stack trace in my `deploy` job. My `build` job with unit tests and code coverage passes.

**main.yaml**:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: src

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:10.8
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: github_actions

        ports:
          - 5433:5432

        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.9
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Test with Unittest
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
        DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
        DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
        DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
        DB_HOST: ${{ secrets.DB_HOST }}
        DB_PORT: ${{ secrets.DB_PORT }}
        DB_ENGINE: ${{ secrets.DB_ENGINE }}
      run: |
        coverage run manage.py test && coverage report --fail-under=75 && coverage xml
        mv coverage.xml ../
    - name: Report coverage to Codecov
      env:
        SECRET_KEY: ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}
        DB_NAME: ${{ secrets.DB_NAME }}
        DB_USER: ${{ secrets.DB_USER }}
        DB_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DB_PASSWORD }}
        DB_HOST: ${{ secrets.DB_HOST }}
        DB_PORT: ${{ secrets.DB_PORT }}
        DB_ENGINE: ${{ secrets.DB_ENGINE }}
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v1
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        files: ./coverage.xml
        directory: ./coverage/reports/
        fail_ci_if_error: true

  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Deploy to App Engine
        id: deploy
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-appengine@v0.2.0
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          deliverables: app.yaml
          credentials: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
          version: v1
      - name: Test
        run: curl "${{ steps.deploy.outputs.url }}
```

**app.yaml**:

```
runtime: python39

instance_class: B1
service: deploy
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 10m
```

Here are the two errors I'm getting:
[image]

I also get another strange error in **app.yaml**, which causes the workflow to not run. I thought from the Google App Engine documentation for this file that we didn't need to include an `on` trigger. I'm not sure if it's caused by the error in `main.yaml`.

Is there an easy way to fix this error?

UPDATE: After trying `v0.4.0` of the GitHub Action, I get the same error, but I found out that my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` are causing the error.

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "***",
    "private_key_id": "***",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----***=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "***@appspot.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "***",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/***%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I replaced all private information with `***`, but the JSON is definitely still valid.

Comment: Can you try with `deploy-appengine@v0.4.0`? Does it work?

Comment: Ok, I tried v0.4, and I get the same error, but it shows that my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS errors out, although it's definitely valid JSON. I'll update my question with what the credentials look like.

Comment: do you mind also adding the whole error about the credentials? Thanks

Comment: @CamilleDunning Were you able to solve this? Just ran into this, too